# PUN 2 Getting and Setting Custom Properties

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'm still relatively new to Photon since the depreciation of UNet. I'm having trouble getting and setting local custom properties. I'm trying to have two different teams (players and angels) be chosen. Each player starts as a spectator. A certain percentage of players are chosen to be the angels, and the rest are assigned as players. I can manage to get and set the property of a randomly chosen player, but I can't seem to assign the values for the remaining. The snippet of code is below.

```
private IEnumerator TeamBalance()
    {
        angelCount = Mathf.Floor(PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length * angelPercent);
        currentAngels = angelCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < angelCount;)
        {
            int index = Random.Range(0, PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length);
            if (PhotonNetwork.PlayerList[index].CustomProperties["team"].ToString() == "spectator")
            {
                PhotonNetwork.PlayerList[index].CustomProperties["team"] = "angel";
                i++;
            }
        }

        foreach (var player in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList)
        {
            if (player.CustomProperties["team"].ToString() == "spectator")
            {
                player.CustomProperties["team"] = "player";
            }
        }

        yield return null;
    }
```

The end result for 3 players ends up picking 1 angel, but with 2 spectators still remaining.

Comment: Did you try to rather use `string.Equals` instead of `==`? What happens instead? Did you try debugging and check whether the according line of code is reached at all? And actually why is this a Coroutine? If you only yield in the end you can also make it a normal method

Comment: I would also recommend to use some `const string`s here just to eliminate the possibility of typos

Comment: Try using the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Player.SetCustomProperties function to set properties instead of assigning them directly. This allows PUN to track what’s been changed and update properly.
https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_player.html#a0c1010eda4f775ff56f8c86b026be41e

Comment: Hey, I'm having trouble understanding how to format my SetCustomProperties. Not sure how to get a hashtable out the custom properties that I already added.

Comment: You need to create a hashtable and then add the keys and values you want changed in custom properties dictionary.
In your case, it will be like this:
`ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable teamProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable() {["team"] = "player"};
player.SetCustomProperties(teamProperties);`
Note that you need to use PUN's Hashtable explicitly, because otherwise compiler will assume built-in C# Hashtable and produce an error.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand. I still don't get how I would set different teams. Since I am creating a new hashtable with a key AND a value, how would I be able to change the value for the specific key? If wanted to change to a spectator, for example, would it just be:
```
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable teamProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable() {["team"] = "spectator"};
```

Comment: By calling SetCustomProperties with the hashtable, you are telling PUN which properties to change and which values to set. This function does not throw away the old CustomProperties dictionary, but rather adjusts it with new values, and notifies the other clients that it has changed. Hope that helps.